# How to divide train and test datasets into ratios in R for a decision tree?

Tags: r, testing, decision-tree, sample

Here's the instructions in the homework and I have two separate code implementations but I'm having trouble interpreting what the instructions are asking:

Use the following ratios to divide the data set;

a) 50 train: 50 test

b) 75 train: 25 test

c) 25 train: 75 test

d) 85 train: 15 test

The parameter SplitRatio in sample.split is confusing me, I've checked the documentation but it's not clear to me what it does, it looks like a percentage of success to me to determine true or false for the decision tree. **Question:** do I make SplitRatio 0.5 to have a 50 train, 50 test ratio or do I just have the dataset itself modified to include a random seed of 50 rows, 75, 25, etc.? I have SplitRatio set to 0.9 here and the dataset itself is modified to only include 50 entries. If I change it to 0.5 it dramatically changes the decision tree, same thing if I include the entire dataset instead of 50.

```
#---------------------------------
#    Ratio 50 Train : 50 Test
#---------------------------------

set.seed(1)
set50 <- sample(nrow(cancerdata), 50, replace=FALSE)
#set50

cancerset5050 <- cancerdata[set50,]
cancerset5050

?sample.split

spl = sample.split(cancerset5050$study.Diagnosis, SplitRatio = 0.9)
spl

dataTrain = subset(cancerset5050, spl==TRUE)
dataTest = subset(cancerset5050, spl==FALSE)

m5050 <- J48(as.factor(study.Diagnosis)~., dataTrain) 

summary(m5050)

## visualization the model
## use partykit package
if(require("partykit", quietly = TRUE)) plot(m5050)

dataTest.pred <- predict(m5050, newdata = dataTest)
table(dataTest$study.Diagnosis, dataTest.pred)
```

Comment: Which package are you using for `sample.split`?

Comment: Library caTools, sorry for not including that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your understanding of `sample.split` function is correct. If you set `SplitRatio = 0.5`, then you will have 50% of the samples in training set, and the remaining 50% in the test set as you have done it.

I think you should convert your response variable to factor before you separate the training and test sets.

That is

```
cancerset5050$study.Diagnosis <- as factor(cancerset5050$study.Diagnosis)
```

And the move on to train and test

```
dataTrain = subset(cancerset5050, spl==TRUE)
dataTest = subset(cancerset5050, spl==FALSE)

m5050 <- J48(study.Diagnosis ~., dataTrain)
```

Comment: For some reason I can't use the line you suggested, here's several attempts, the commented out ones wouldn't work, I'll post in next comment

Comment: ```#cancersamp$study.Diagnosis <- as.factor(cancersamp$study.Diagnosis)```

Comment: ```m5050 <- J48(as.factor(study.Diagnosis)~., dataTrain)```

Comment: ```#m5050 <- J48(as.factor(cancersamp$study.Diagnosis)~., dataTrain)```

Comment: ```#m5050 <- J48(cancersamp$study.Diagnosis~., dataTrain)```

Comment: The reason I'm concerned is that the sample has been randomized and it's a sample from the original dataset, it also has the specific columns I want to look at as nodes, study.Diagnosis is going back to before I did all of that, right?

Comment: (The last #m5050 wouldn't been implemented after the first one was implemented for the as.factor function)

Comment: Maybe the cancersamp is matrix. In that case, `cancersamp$study.Diagnosis <- as.factor(cancersamp$study.Diagnosis)` would not work.

Comment: I think you should try to make your question a bit clear.

Comment: I ended up just sticking with ```m5050 <- J48(as.factor(study.Diagnosis)~., dataTrain)``` but I did think your suggestion looked cleaner I just didn't know how to implement it, thanks for all of your help!